# FFmpeg: undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I try to build library and get:

```
undefined reference to 'main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is a .c file I've added in jni folder:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "creator.h"

// Use to safely invoke ffmpeg multiple times from the same Activity
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator_run(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray args)
{
int i = 0;
int argc = 0;
char **argv = NULL;

if (args != NULL) {
    argc = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, args);
    argv = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc);

    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        jstring str = (jstring)(*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, args, i);
        argv[i] = (char *)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, NULL);
    }
}

main(argc, argv);
}
```

This is a .h file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator */

#ifndef _Included_com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator
#define _Included_com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator
 * Method:    run
 * Signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_appunite_ffmpeg_FFmpegCreator_run(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

When I comment main(argc, argv) - the build is successful, otherwise - got this error.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  `main` is generally not called by your code -- it is the entry point for your program.  Are you trying to call this C++ code from Java?  In that case your `main` should be in a `.java` file and you will run your program with `$ java JavaFileName.java`.  

You are getting the link error because you are calling `main` without having defined it.

Comment: Where is the `main` function defined? Shared objects don't have a `main` function in the same way as an application, so if you based this on some example code you should try to find something that was written for Android.

Comment: Have you defined a "main" function? The code just prepares argc and argv and passes them to your main().

Comment: I need to run someting like "ffmpeg -i image.jpeg -i audio.mp3 out.avi". So I need to set it in args. I was doing like here https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/Project/jni/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg_android.c
I also tried such a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372512/ffmpeg-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-while-calling-runnable-class
But there was another error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/Project/jni/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg_android.c is doing something a bit odd.

It runs as a Java program, calls the C code in `ffmpeg_android.c`, and that code calls into the ffmpeg C `main` method (the same one that is called when you run ffmpeg directly from the command line).  This is probably not the best way to accomplish what you want.  Ideally, you would use the ffmpeg APIs (like [libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libavc.html)) to do your encoding / decoding.

Nonetheless, your method should still work, and I suspect the reason you are getting a link error is because you are not linking in the ffmpeg code.  Can you post the command you are running to build the C code?  Make sure you are either including the ffmpeg source code in your sources or you have `-lffmpeg` somewhere in your linkline.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I use this library: https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg. And build it in such a way it's told there. But in Android.mk and build_android.sh I can't find any -lffmpeg. Should I add it in Android.mk?

Comment: No, `Android.mk` already includes the ffmpeg object files.  If you run `build_android.sh` without your JNI sources does it build OK?

Comment: Yes, it builds ok, without any error if I comment main(argc, argv).

Comment: But in Android.mk I've added my creator.c in LOCAL_SRC_FILES

Comment: I am not familiar with this library, but if you can paste the g++/gcc command that the makefiles are running I can take a look.

Comment: If I've understood right,
http://pastebin.com/uETTcM2d
http://pastebin.com/0Qfg5KGt
http://pastebin.com/ENUB0j3L
http://pastebin.com/VhxVgNve
http://pastebin.com/n79Y6UkK